# How exactly does Cargo detect file changes?

Tags: rust-cargo, lsyncd

tl;dr: I want to know what `cargo` uses to determine whether or not a file has changed to debug a problem I've observed in my build system setup.

## Description

I currently have `lsyncd` setup to mirror project files onto a remote linux machine where I compile code via `ENVVARS_HERE=$my_values cargo build`. `lsyncd`'s use of `rsync` w/ the `archive flag` unfortunately seems to not copy over whatever attribute it is that `cargo` uses to determine whether or not a file has been edited:

I have a workspace set up:

```
workspace
+ crateA
  + ...
+ crateB
  + ...
```

where `crateB` depends on `crateA`. Henceforth, 'remote machine' refers to the machine on which `cargo` is invoked, and 'local machine' refers to a machine editing the code that `lsyncd` then passes onto the 'remote machine'. I will use 'recently' to refer to any time during which the dependencies of the action being described have not been changed relative to the state being described in a manner I am aware of.

### Situation A

Initial state:

- workspace has been copied from the local machine to the remote machine
- `lsyncd` **is not** running on the local machine
- `crateB` has been compiled recently by `cargo build` on the remote machine

Perform:

- edit source file in `crateB` on the remote machine
- invoke `cargo build` on the remote machine

Result:

- `crateB` is recompiled by `cargo` on the remote machine

### Situation B

Initial state:

- workspace has been copied from the local machine to the remote machine
- `lsyncd` **is** running on the local machine (see notes below regarding configuration)
- `crateB` has been compiled recently by `cargo build` on the remote machine (see notes regarding timing relative to `lsyncd`'s operation modes)

Perform:

- edit `crateB` file on local machine
- wait for synchronization to trigger and complete
- invoke `cargo build` on remote machine

Result:

- `crateA` compiles on the remote machine, followed by `crateB`

### Notes

- `lsyncd` was run both with and without `archive = true` (which to the best of my knowledge sets rsync's `archive` flag to copy 'most' metadata, where 'most' appears to miss whatever it is that `cargo` cares about), with no observed change in the results.
- compilation for initial state where `lsyncd` was present was tested for the following cases with no observed changes in the results: compilation *before* `lsyncd`'s initial pass, and compilation *after* `lsyncd`'s initial pass
- the target directory for `lsyncd` on the remote machine is on a `tmpfs` filesystem (if that makes some arcane difference)

## Question

I want a way to suss out what's going on here, both in this situation with `lsyncd` and in the future if/when I give up on `lsyncd` for some other approach that stumbles on a similar problem. Sources regarding `cargo` on e.g. SO reference the use of timestamps, but there are many kinds of timestamps and which timestamp they refer to is unclear.

What *exactly* does `cargo` check for when determining whether or not a file has changed?

Answer (score 2):

So cargo uses [fingerprints](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/src/cargo/core/compiler/fingerprint.rs) to track change metadata.

Seems to me from reading the code that it's related to `mtime`, the modified time; [fingerprint::find_stale_file](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/src/cargo/core/compiler/fingerprint.rs) and [paths::mtime_recursive](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/crates/cargo-util/src/paths.rs#L225).